# Show/hide a message if date time match with API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and I'm trying to do something tricky and I do not know how to start. I need to apply some style if the actual time correspond to the time that the `API` response shows. The response is something like this:

```
data: {
  actual: {progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "18:00"}
}
```

If the actual time is between `15:00` and `18:00` I have to apply a style to some `<td>` on my `HTML`.

I can get the actual time doing this:

```
function refreshTime()
{
    var dateString = new Date().toLocaleString(
        "en-US",
        {timeZone: "America/Sao_Paulo"}
    );
    var formattedString = dateString.replace(", ", " - ");
    console.log(formattedString);
}

setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

but I don't know how to compare the current time whit the data object that comes from the `API`. Note, I don't want to use `moment.js` or another library. Any help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the starting/ending hours and minutes from the api response, you can use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
let data = {
  actual: {progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "18:00"} 
};

let start = data.actual.progorig.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/);
let end = data.actual.end.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/);

console.log(start[0] + " - " + end[0]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Now, to check whether the current hours and minutes are within the range obtained from the api response, you can proceed like this:

```js
let data = {
  actual: {progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "18:00"} 
};

let start = data.actual.progorig.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0];
let end = data.actual.end.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0];

function refreshTime()
{
    let currH = new Date().getHours();
    let currM = new Date().getMinutes();
    currH = currH < 10 ? "0" + currH : currH.toString();
    currM = currM < 10 ? "0" + currM : currM.toString();
    let currTime = currH + ":" + currM;
    let bCheck = currTime > start && currTime < end;

    console.log(`Is current time of ${currTime} between ${start} and ${end}? ${bCheck}`);
}

setInterval(refreshTime, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

## Update as per commentaries:

> **API Response** is: `{progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "1800"}`

```js
let data = {
  actual: {progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "1800"} 
};

let start = data.actual.progorig.match(/\d{2}:?\d{2}/);
start = start[0].replace(":", "");
let end = data.actual.end.match(/\d{2}:?\d{2}/);
end = end[0].replace(":", "");

function refreshTime()
{
    let currH = new Date().getHours();
    let currM = new Date().getMinutes();
    currH = currH < 10 ? "0" + currH : currH.toString();
    currM = currM < 10 ? "0" + currM : currM.toString();
    let currTime = currH + currM;
    let bCheck = currTime > start && currTime < end;

    console.log(`Is current time of ${currTime} between ${start} and ${end}? ${bCheck}`);
}

setInterval(refreshTime, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shidersz i try yor code and dosen t work.. the end param is a string and he has not :  I think me by there is the problem so the console.log says: `Is current time of 19:03 between 17:30 and 1949? false`  the response is  `actual: {progorig: "15:00 program One ", end: "1800"}`

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei Well, you can do some changes on my current code to make it work, but the idea still holds, if you can't figure out in some time, I will give some update to my code.

Comment: @AgustinWaldbottvonBassenhei Check the last snippet example, it should work with the new API response you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Please gone through below sample code it could solve your problem.

```js
var APIData = {
        actual: { start: "15:00", end: "18:00" }
    }

    function refreshTime() {
        var dateString = new Date();
        var strts = APIData.actual.start.split(":");
        var ends = APIData.actual.end.split(":");
        var customData = {
            actual: {
                start: new Date(dateString.setHours(strts[0], strts[1], 00)),
                end: new Date(dateString.setHours(ends[0], ends[1], 00)),
            }
        }
        var isConditionsFalls = dateString > customData.actual.start && dateString < customData.actual.end;
        console.log(isConditionsFalls);
        if (isConditionsFalls) {
            //update the UI
        }
    }
    setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

Comment: tanks @DMishra but your code throw me an error :  `Octal numeric literals not allowed in strict mode`